# Handling leap seconds with date

Tags: time, date, timezone

I am running clockspeed-0.62 (DJB software) on Ubuntu 13.10. I have setup timezones so that `/usr/share/zoneinfo` is a link to `/usr/share/right`, and my `/etc/leapsecs.dat` is up-to-date, i.e contains 25 leap seconds.

Could someone help me to understand (and to solve) why `date -u` command shows time 25 seconds ahead `export TZ=UTC; date`?

Output of `date; (export TZ=UTC; date); date -u`:

```
Mon Feb  3 22:33:56 CET 2014
Mon Feb  3 21:33:56 UTC 2014
Mon Feb  3 21:34:21 UTC 2014
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TZ=UTC` makes glibc use the zoneinfo file named "UTC", which in your case is `/usr/share/zoneinfo/right/UTC` containing leap second adjustments.

The `-u` option is actually equivalent to setting **`TZ=UTC0`**. Since there is **no zoneinfo file named `UTC0`**, the setting gets reinterpreted as being in the "std offset" format instead  (as in [tzset(3)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man3/tzset.3.html)). In this format, the first three letters are just used as the visible name, and **the "0" is used as a simple offset from UTC** (that is, offset from system clock).